# Why is there a tax bracket less than $2000 wide with 35% marginal tax rate in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-brackets

It seems as if anyone that's getting paid $398,351 – $400,000 would simply lower their salary to the $183,251 – $398,350 tax bracket and get 2% lower income taxes. Does the bracket serve any purpose, or is it simply some type of bureaucratic necessity?

Comment: How would they "simply lower their salary" ? Also, the income tax rates are *marginal* rates, so the "2% lower" would apply only to the income above the threshold, not to the entire amount of income.

Comment: Not 2% lower income taxes; brackets are marginal: http://money.stackexchange.com/q/23560/24700

Comment: All Tax systems tend to have these odd tax bands where you get off effects

@ChrisW.Rea Salary Sacrifice or Charity Donations can be used if your just over one tax band to manage your tax liability

Comment: The extra 2% is basically $33 for the extra $1,650 of income (above the lower tax rate).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recognize the numbers you show to reflect the 2013 tax brackets. In 2015 the top of the chart for singles looks like:

[image]

Before this remarkably cute little tax bracket appeared, the top rate was 35%. Instead of simply eliminating it, for singles, congress started the next bracket, 39.6% at $413K.

The brackets for married filing joint look a bit saner, with 35% running from $411K-$465K.

Comment: This seems like Congress trying to pull a fast one.  "We didn't increase your rate from 35% to 39.6%, we just added a new bracket!"

Comment: Right. The bracket runs for $1700. A bit silly, I'd say. These $1700 are taxed at 35%, then it's 39.6% on up.

Comment: The administrative cost needed to deal with such a small tax bracket probably outweighs any tax revenue they get from it.

Comment: I'd say that most returns that have a "cost" are done by computer, in which case there's no incremental cost. Is there any pro doing returns by hand?

Answer (score 4):

Eagle,

It may not be clear yet, but the tax rate in a certain bracket is only applied to the income within that range.

For example, let's say you earn 40k a year.  And there are two tax rates which concern you:
10% - on earnings up to 25,000
15% - 25,001-50,000

According to this scheme, you would pay 10% on the first 25k (2,500) and then you would pay 15% on the remainder (c. 2,250).  The remainder which incurs the 15% tax rate is your salary, 40k, less the bottom end of the highest bracket, in this case, 25,001.

I hope I did my math right there...

Comment: Note that the rates apply not to raw earnings, but to what's left after exemptions & deductions.  So a single person earning $40K/yr would have $3950 personal exemption and 6200 standard deduction (in 2014), so would pay 15% of $4850, or $757.50.  (I think - at least if my math's wrong, the IRS hasn't noticed yet!)

Comment: Hmmm, I see money scheme...